# Python: Seperate multiple of same class (from html)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

the information I want to seperate is from: https://deathsnacks.com/wf/ (Alerts)

From using inspect element you can see that the class name is: list-group alerts-container

So I got this code so far:

````
url = "https://deathsnacks.com/wf/"
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    alert = soup.find('ul', {'class': 'list-group alerts-container'}).text
    msg = "```"
    msg += alert
    msg += "```"
````

However, the output of above gives out all lines of currently available alerts, but not on individual lines (or seperated), how could I go about seperating them.

Output:

[image: looks like this]

Comment: I realize it's explained extremely poorly, the best way to describe how I want it formatted is the planet name, mission type, level, the reward (e.g BardAltHelmetBlueprint, or 100 endo), the credits (cr) and time remaining all on one line, for each one. Have a look at the website to fully understand https://deathsnacks.com/wf/

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it, the HTML you are retrieving from the soup is

```
<ul class="list-group alerts-container">
    <li class="list-group-item"> ... </li>
    <li class="list-group-item"> ... </li>
    <li class="list-group-item"> ... </li>
</ul>
```

To retrieve all these items individually, you should use `soup.find_all('li')`. This returns the individual items in a list.

````
alert = soup.find('ul', {'class': 'list-group alerts-container'})
items = alert.find_all('li')
msg = '```\n'
msg += '\n'.join(e.text for e in items)
msg += '\n```'
````